# Linebreak in newcommand and reference to hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, koma-script

I try to define the name of a document and to use this name in hyperref resp. as the file's properties etc., but for some reason the pdftitle and the pdfkeyowrd option seem to clash with the line break, is there a way to circumnavigate this issue, thanks?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\Titel}{\mbox{Line 1} \\ \mbox{Line 2}}

\usepackage[            pdftex,
                        pdftitle={\Titel},          % -->crash
                        pdfkeywords={\Titel},       % -->crash
                        pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright} 
\Titel
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know the the pdftitle can't be displayed with a newline... and the searching for a keyword with a linebreak would complicate things. Furthermore, `\\ ` is not allowed in a PDFString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the text section of the `.pdf` file `\\` is interpreted correctly, but the compilation process complains about unallowed characters in PDFString. It's possible to force `\texorpdfstring{\\}{^^J}` with the TeX - primitive `^^J` newline which at least is interpreted as a link break in the keywords section.

In addition, the `hyperref` manual recommends to specify `pdftitle` etc. **after** the package has been loaded, i.e. using the `\hypersetup` command.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\Titel}{\mbox{Line 1} \texorpdfstring{\\}{^^J} \mbox{Line 2}}


\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}%

\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle={\Titel},
  pdfkeywords={\Titel}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright} 
  \Titel
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]